# How do I use async.map() properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

I'm trying to use **async.map()** function to iterate through an array of words and fetch search results.
The function is given an array of keywords, and it accesses the NYT API to search & fetch articles related to the keyword.

Here's my code snippet:

```
const searchKeywords = (keywords, callback) => {

// list of keywords (for example: ["Joe Biden", "Manhattan", "U.S. Politics"])
let keywords_list = keywords

  async.map(keywords_list, function(keyword, cb) {
    
     // this is an Async function that accesses NYT API to fetch article data in JSON type
     searchArticles(keyword, (error, results) => {
       keyword = results
     })
  })

  // return modified array to the callback function
  callback(null, keywords_list)

}
```

For instance, if searchKeywords takes in an array ["Joe Biden", "Manhattan", "U.S. Politics"],
I want the callback to be called with an array that looks like:

```
[{'Articles related to Joe Biden'}, {'Articles related to Manhattan'}, ...]
```

But apparently, the callback function still gets the unchanged, initial array with keywords only.
Is it because callback is called even before all keywords are processed in async.map()?

Comment: I'm surprise using `async.map` isn't throwing an error of some kind. Isn't `async` a reserved word in JS?

Comment: You need to import async library to use that, in fact but I omitted that line of code in the snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that. I just wondered how a library could use a reserved word like that.

Comment: @ZenoDallaValle Sorry, haven't got the time to test it yet but I marked yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const searchKeywords = (keywords, callback) => {
        // list of keywords (for example: ["Joe Biden", "Manhattan", "U.S. Politics"]
        const promise = new Promise((resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
          resolutionFunc(
            keywords.map((k) => {
              //put search function here then return results
              return null;
            })
          );
        });
        promise.then((result) => {
          callback(result, keywords)
        });
      };

      function onClickBtn() {
        searchKeywords(['joe'], console.log);
        console.log('this is executed before');
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="onClickBtn()">
      search ['joe']
    </button>
```

this should work, I tested for you. You have to add error handling but it's doing the job.

Basically you define your promise, then it's called and when promise is solved callback is called.

Comment: Just tested with node.js (v14.15.4) and it's working well.